# Renaming index leads to data corruption in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading a csv and writing it out as a compressed csv. I use the following code

```py
inp = pd.read_csv(inp_path)
inp.to_csv(filename, compression='gzip',encoding='utf-8')
```

And it just works fine

I need to rename the index as `rownum`, and I use the following code

```py
inp = pd.read_csv(inp_path)
inp.index.names = ['rownum']
inp.to_csv(filename, compression='gzip',encoding='utf-8')
```

this leads to an error while reading the written file

`Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached`

I'm doing this for 4 files, but I run into this issue for just one file.
Is there something wrong with what I'm doing ? Or is this a possible data issue ?

**OR**

Is there another way I can do this rename that will help me bypass this problem ?

**EDIT**

As suggested in the comments. Tried the following code

```py
inp = pd.read_csv(inp_path)
row_count = len(inp)
index_row = range(0, row_count)
inp.insert(0, "rownum", index_row)
inp.to_csv(filename, compression='gzip',encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Still running into the same error mentioned above while trying to read the file

Comment: Why do you need to rename the index names? Where I’m going with that question, is why not just add a new column with the value you’re renaming, and pass `index=False` into the `to_csv` function?

Comment: @Parfait, Yes, the file is not corrupt when I write without index name change

Comment: Try using `index_label` argument of [`DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Comment: @Parfait tried that, it made no difference. Still the same error

Comment: Hmmm...testing on my end with random data returns no error with same posted lines. This may be data-related. Maybe encoding?

Comment: @S3DEV, I tried doing that. No issue while writing. Run into the same error on reading. Once again, works for the other 3 files. Issue only with one file. Possible reasons ?

Comment: @Parfait, the issue I have is only for 1 of the 4 files. The other 3 files have no issue. Trying to understand possible reasons ?